# How to perform modal while clicking on delete it should particular delete that data.?

Tags: javascript, php, html, angular

I have Tried calling it,but i don't know to pass the actual data is not getting it is reflecting me undefined.what should i do for passing the data from one component to another page modal component.

I  have a crud application where i click on the delete button and it should reflect me a modal, in which i want to ensure delete or not ,while clicking on delete it should delete the data specific.

stackblitz.com/edit/angular-orasdfsdfbr4d

while clicking on delete button after confirmation it should delete.and getting error of the undefined id.

Comment: add what you have done so far

Answer (score 0):

When an expected modal is to be opened, you should always check the id or data-target of the button of the delete.

If you're using tables or data table, most likely the ids do not match the modal target.

If it is component issue pls, upload what have you done so far.

UPDATE:

If the id is undefined (based on my experience), you can save the id in a service to be deleted, to save its state. If this is not the problem, then the mapping of your id to be passed has some issues.

Comment: cruxyl, i am getting undefined id.
i am trying to make a call of open model from the component and from that it navigates to it component and shows the message ,howsoever while clicking i just want to perform deleting task on that modal in which the page is navigated.

Comment: on datatable i am getting index properly but while giving it functionality of the popup in modal it does not passes it gives me error of undefined id.

Comment: undefined id of the data that you want to get deleted right? When clickign the confirm button on the pop up delete modal, it says undefined id, of what data to be deleted?

Answer (score 0):

Hello @jay shah for delete confirmation, use sweetalert.js . Follow link for documentation : https://sweetalert.js.org/docs/
here is a sample code:

```
swal({
  cancel: {
    text: "Delete?",
    value: null,
    visible: false,
    className: "",
    closeModal: true,
  },
  confirm: {
    text: "OK",
    value: true,
    visible: true,
    className: "",
    closeModal: true
//Action after confirmation here

  }
});
```

To delete a specific data in a loop, use what I call JaPH (Javascript and PHP) such that you execute a javascript code in a php loop; each data on the row should be ID with the ID of that record in the database. That way you won't have ID conflict

Comment: i am runing in the angular dug, how will it reflect on it i don't know actually

Comment: The confirmation thing can be solved. it's the same js, just different libraries
and for the delete function, you can use the same logic I use for php ...
just fetch the data from the database in a loop; and use the ID of each record in the database to id each row on the HTML table then capture the data ID in an HTML input hidden form. That way, you can pass the ID of that data via jquery ajax

Comment: Can you show a fraction of your code showing how you retrieve data from the database

Comment: actually it is in the form of angular and taking the data from services.now when getting values it does'nt get's the data of it